# Windows using wrong display driver

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, asus-laptop, display-driver

I'm having a problem with my Windows 10 Asus laptop. I think a recent Windows update might have caused a bit of a problem. Previously, before the update, I was using an Intel display driver. However, after the update, I noticed that my driver suddenly switched to Microsoft Basic Display Driver. This is causing major slow down in a few of my programs. I've tried installing the latest Intel driver, but the installation keeps failing. Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Can you report on the message you get with the installation failure? Which driver are you trying to install (where did you get it from?). Are you sure it was an update that caused it or is this a guess? What Intel display chipset do you have?

Comment: The message I get from the failure is "The setup program failed to install one or more device drivers. Setup will exit." I am trying to install Intel HD Graphics Driver for Windows 10 64bit (3rd Gen & BYT) Version 15.33.38.64.4252 from the Intel Driver Update Utility. The installation gives Intel(R) Display Audio Version 6.16.00.3154 and Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 Version 10.18.10.4252.It is just a guess that the update caused the problem but it seemed most likely due to the fact that it was the only major thing I've done on my computer for awhile. My chip type is Intel(R) HD Graphics Family.

Comment: You may need to manually install the driver (the installer fails quite frequently, often because it believes you should be using manufacturer supplied drivers). Use [these instructions](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005474.html) to do so. The instructions are for Windows 7, but are almost the same, except use the correct driver for your system, and to access device manager hold the Win key, press X, and choose Device Manager from the pop up.

Comment: Windows 10 now installs that they think is the latest greatest drivers, and there is no stopping it, you can postpone update installs but eventually it will install, one reason I cannot use W10 on my notebook, it keeps installing a video driver that causes it not to boot into windows.

Answer (score 0):

> You may need to manually install the driver (the installer fails quite frequently, often because it believes you should be using manufacturer supplied drivers). Use these instructions to do so. The instructions are for Windows 7, but are almost the same, except use the correct driver for your system, and to access device manager hold the Win key, press X, and choose Device Manager from the pop up. – Jonno

Thanks a lot for the help. That seems to have fixed my problem.